# Decrypt Kafka Avro Message

Tags: java, json, stack-overflow, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to parse a kafka message, it's in some encrypted AVRO format. I have the following AvroSchema.avsc avro schema file:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "kafka.events",
    "name": "AvroSchema",
        "fields": [
            { "name": "product_id", "type": "string" },
            { "name": "available_to_promise_quantity", "type": "double" },
            { "name": "online_available_to_promise_quantity", "type": "double" },
            { "name": "stores_available_to_promise_quantity", "type": "double" },
            { "name": "is_infinite_inventory", "type": "boolean", "default" : false },
            { "name": "event_timestamp", "type": "long" },
            { "name": "previous_event", "type": "AvroSchema" }
        ]
 }
```

Now, I have written the following code to get the data in JSON format:

```
for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streams){
    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> consumerIterator = stream.iterator();
    byte[] consumedEncryptedMessage;
    MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> consumedEntry;
    while(consumerIterator.hasNext()){
        consumedEntry = consumerIterator.next();
            if(null != consumedEntry){
                consumedEncryptedMessage = consumedEntry.message();
                    try {
                            Schema schema = null;
                            schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("src/AvroSchema.avsc"));
                            DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
                            Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(consumedEncryptedMessage , null);
                            GenericRecord decryptedmsg = null;
                            decryptedmsg = reader.read(null, decoder);
                            System.out.println(decryptedmsg);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
```

Please help me how to decrypt the message.

The encrypted byte message is of this type: `080-21-0001 :�Aw�@@��A�ǐ�U :�Aw�@@��A`

I made the changes as suggested, and now i have following piece of code:

```
while(consumerIterator.hasNext()){
    consumedEntry = consumerIterator.next();
        if(null != consumedEntry){
            consumedEncryptedMessage = consumedEntry.message();
                try {
                    Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("src/AVROSchema.avsc"));
                    File myfile = new File("/Users/z001ldc/Desktop/myfile.txt");
                    DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
                    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(myfile, consumedEncryptedMessage);
                    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                    DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<GenericRecord>(myfile, reader);
                    while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
                        decryptedMessage = dataFileReader.next(decryptedMessage);
                        System.out.println(decryptedMessage.get("product_id").toString());
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
```

But still I am getting the error as "Not a data file".

Answer (score -1):

Deserializing wont require decryption

First you get your schema line

```
schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("src/AvroSchema.avsc"));
DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
```

Then

```
DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<GenericRecord>(consumedEncryptedMessage, reader);
GenericRecord user = null;
while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
// Reuse user object by passing it to next(). This saves us from
// allocating and garbage collecting many objects for files with
// many items.
user = dataFileReader.next(user);
System.out.println(user);
```

Comment: DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<GenericRecord>(consumedEncryptedMessage, reader);
This line is showing error as consumedEntryMessage is not a file, it is of type byte[]. Should I consume the message as a file?

Comment: Ohhh .. didn't see that you are having chain of events, like specified in schema ATPEvent. Can you please try removing that from your schema for testing and try out saying System.out.println(result.get("product_id").toString()) . Hopefully thats the culprit, rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: Is there any way to use consumedentrymsg in byte array only instead of File, because i am getting that only as a byte array.